# Delaying loading Google Maps API until map is in view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, lazy-loading

I'm developing a plugin using Google Maps JavaScript API v3, and would like to minimize the number of requests this uses on a heavily trafficked website. Currently the map is fairly far down the page, so I'd like to defer loading the API and incurring request costs unless a user actually scrolls down to it and the map is in view.

I can easily check when the map element is actually in view, my question is, does anyone know if the API call counts as a request when the gapi library script itself is loaded? (the URL with the API key in it is loaded into the page), or does the request only count when a map is actually initialized (ie. map = new google.maps.Map()..)?

thanks!

Comment: API call only count if you initialized the map .You can add the setTimeout() for the initialize function for map and see how it is requested. Calling the script without call any function will not trigger any API call.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#dynamic-maps - *A web page or application that displays a map using the Maps JavaScript API. A map is created with the `google.maps.Map()` class. User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `callback` function that the API gives you.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_API_KEY&callback=initMap()"></script>
```

So that it looks like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_API_KEY"></script>
```

and then just call the `initMap()` function at any point in the code

```
a = 45;
b = 2;
initMap(); // Aqui se manda a ejecutar
```

Comment: Even though I don't speak spanish, I still understood this and it's a good approach. That's why code is awesome :)